# Why not make a startup stack overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Do you think it would be a good idea to create a start ups stack overflow where people can discuss business problems, platforms, easy ways of starting business in specific spheres...

Answer (score 24):

Indeed why not?

Someone else had the same idea and started a [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) for it. It is even already in beta:

http://answers.onstartups.com/

:-)

Comment: this could become a reversal

Comment: @tehdoommarine: [Another answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145704/does-high-reputation-mean-more-experience-in-programming/145705#145705) just made it to reversal, first meta gold for me. This one? Perhaps.

Comment: congratulations, and best of luck getting two in 1 day. very good answer to a not so good question, so i think you deserve another.

Comment: your 'indeed why not?' is wrong because you know the site it already exists, it is basically suggesting having a duplicate site will be ok o.O

Comment: @ajax333221 Would it helped if he had put a ;) behind it? I think it's pretty clear to everyone what Martijn means, and that's not the explanation you're giving...

Answer (score 1):

Quick stats:

[Startup SE site](http://answers.onstartups.com/) is in public beta mode, and receiving 6.7 questions per day, and 97% are answered.

Comment: I just registered there, and found it most awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd find more open questions on this topic than real Q&A interrogations. Especially as most very concrete and precise questions are linked to geographic/commercial areas.

And then you'll discover that other formats, like the one of [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/) or [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/startups), are more adapted to those discussions.

And another point : I'd be very sorry to discover that people having technical programming questions would go on another SE site just because they work in a startup...