# Does anyone think reputation is a measure of trust? or is the FAQ misleading

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does high reputation mean more experience in programming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145704/does-high-reputation-mean-more-experience-in-programming)

Reputation can be a measure of:

- How long you've been using the site.
- How good you are at gathering reputation

I can't see a big number as being any more indication that the users answer could be correct.

Take for example if I give a well meaning but incorrect/misguided answer to a question. If I recieve 2 upvotes and 6 downvotes I've made a net profit of +4 rep.

So users who give harmful answers can be thought reputable.

Or the joke questions again. If someone hits the rep cap on a joke question will that person really be more trusted?

Discuss please.

Comment: Reputation ~ amount of time you've spent.

Comment: I know that the words aren't the same but the explanation of what rep is will be. <the sell> This should be closed as a dupe because otherwise "Is reputation a measure of [pick something] are all not duplicates </the sell>

Comment: Rep alone is not a sufficient metric to deduce a persons knowledge, trustworthiness, influence, etc. I believe this has been discusses many many times before on meta.

Comment: In my opinion it's same question as "Is money measure of how good the person is?".

Comment: not according to the faq @ShaWizDowArd and it's probably not that bad I hope

Comment: @Wes what faq? What do you mean?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: It says "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you". It does not say "Reputation is a rough measurement of how good and correct are your posts" so no, I don't think it's misleading.

Comment: it's too hard to loose too even this question has an upvote which severely limits the damage that should be done by suggesting something harmful.  or would do if this wasn't meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Off the bat, I have nothing against the joke question, this is more to disagree with those pretending reputation doesn't exist.*

---

These users need to stop kidding themselves.

> Reputation is a rough measurement of **how much the community trusts you;**

*Reputation is important* within the scope of Stack Overflow. Whether that may be through

- points
- famous name in Microsoft, XYZ company
- $$$

It's important. Whoever says otherwise is fooling themselves. *You know why?*

Because the great deletion wars, reputation debates and historical locks *would never have had to happen*.

Guess what is one number you are bound to find on most pages?

> That's right! Your reputation.

What's the default ordering of the user page?

> Reputation

If I had the power to take away 10,000 rep from each user setting them back past the unpassable 1 rep barrier, they *will* notice, they *will* uproar.

So to answer your question, **yes they will be trusted**, because no one will remember who asked that joke question, you will see their name on a next question and think... oh they have a lot of reputation! You go to their profile and see their language specific badge points are high! Are you going to dig through each and every question to be sure the user didn't gain the point from a joke question?

Nope.

The *majority* of SO users don't sit down and ponder

- how much experience a user has
- where they got their education
- what other languages they know
- whether they only answer low hanging fruit questions

---

*This is the flaw that SO throws under the rug and pretends like 4 out of 5 new users don't believe reputation has a measure*

**The cake is a lie**

Comment: The _cake_ is a lie? Can you explain that one to me?

Comment: @Ben It's a reference to the game [Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_%28video_game%29).

Comment: What's this about an unpassable 1 rep barrier?

Comment: @TheGuyWhoDisagreesWithYou, you can't go below 1 rep, no matter how much you get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking from experience, higher rep users tend to give better quality answers.

Sure, some people can theoretically grind rep without being good answerers,  but having higher reputation is normally a good indicator.

Comment: Not always. But most of the time, high rep users have more experience with the site, so they (hopefully) know how to give a good answer. But if you want a measure of experience you better look at the upvotes for the specific tag.